# Python find words within a user input word game

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to write a program that allows the user to input a word then find all words of length 4 or greater hidden within that word that are in a word text file. So far my code can detect the words in the user inputted word that aren't jumbled. For example if I type in `houses`, the output will show `house`, `houses`, `ho`, `us`, `use`, `uses`. It should also recognize `hose`, `hoses`, `shoe`, `shoes`, `hues`, etc.

I know itertools is the simplest solution but I want to use a different method using only loops, dictionaries, and lists.

Here is my code so far:

```
def main():
    filename = open('dictionary.txt').readlines()
    word_list = []
    for line in filename:
        word_list.append(line.strip())

    print 'Lets Play Words within a Word!\n'
    word = raw_input('Enter a word: ')
    words_left = 0
    for words in word_list:
        letters = list(words)
        if words in word:
            print words
            words_left += 1
        else:
            False
```

The output format I'm trying to create should look like so:

```
Lets play Words within a Word!

Enter a word: exams #user inputted word

exams ---  6 words are remaining
> same #user types in guess
Found!  # prints 'Found!' if above word is found in the dictionary.txt file

exams ---  5 words are remaining
> exam
Found!

exams ---  4 words are remaining
> mesa
Found!

exams ---  3 words are remaining
> quit() #if they type this command in the game will end
```

So my question is, after entering the base word (in the ex it's EXAMS), how do I determine the total number of words within that word and if the user inputted word guesses are in the text file? Also print if the word was found.

Comment: And what is your question? Try to keep you question focused and do not mix more topics.

Comment: Why would it recognize `shoes`?

Answer (score 0):

A naive implementation (using `collections.Counter`):

```
>>> all_words = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'hose', 'hoses', 'shoe', 'shoes', 'hues', 'house', 'houses', 'ho', 'us', 'use', 'uses', 'shoe', 'same', 'exam', 'mesa', 'mass']

>>> def find_hidden(user_input):
        from collections import Counter
        user_word_counts = Counter(user_input)
        for word in all_words:
            isvalid = True
            for letter, count in Counter(word).iteritems():
                if user_word_counts[letter] == 0 or user_word_counts[letter] < count:
                    isvalid = False
                    break
            if isvalid: yield word


>>> list(find_hidden("houses"))
['hose', 'hoses', 'shoe', 'shoes', 'hues', 'house', 'houses', 'ho', 'us', 'use', 'uses', 'shoe']
>>> list(find_hidden("exams"))
['same', 'exam', 'mesa']
```

Or,

Using permutations:

```
>>> all_words = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'hose', 'hoses', 'shoe', 'shoes', 'hues', 'house', 'houses', 'ho', 'us', 'use', 'uses', 'shoe', 'same', 'exam', 'mesa', 'mass']
>>> def permutations(s, n): # could use itertools.permutations
        if n == 1:
            for c in s:
                yield c
        for i in range(len(s)):
            for p in permutation(s[:i]+s[i+1:], n-1):
                yield s[i] + p


>>> def find_hidden(input_str):
        for word_len in range(2, len(input_str)+1):
            for word in permutations(input_str, word_len):
                if word in all_words:
                    yield word


>>> set(find_hidden("houses"))
set(['use', 'hose', 'shoes', 'houses', 'house', 'us', 'hues', 'hoses', 'uses', 'ho', 'shoe'])
>>> set(find_hidden("exams"))
set(['mesa', 'exam', 'same'])
```

Comment: The OP explicitly said he knew `itertools` is the simplest approach but he doesn't want to use it...

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
# read from file in actual implementation
all_words = [
    "foo", "bar", "baz", "hose", "hoses", "shoe", "shoes", "hues", "house",
    "houses", "ho", "us", "use", "uses", "shoe", "same", "exam", "mesa", "mass"]

RETAIN_ORDERING = False

def matches(inp, word):
    if inp[0] == word[0]:
        return (
            True if len(word) == 1 else
            False if len(inp) == 1 else
            matches(inp[1:], word[1:]))
    else:
        return matches(inp[1:], word) if len(inp) >= 2 else False

# with sorting enabled, "houses" will also match "shoe"; otherwise not
def maybe_sort(x):
    return x if RETAIN_ORDERING else ''.join(sorted(x))

inp = raw_input("enter a word: ")

results = [word for word in all_words if matches(maybe_sort(inp), maybe_sort(word))]

print results
```

**Output:**

```
$ python matches.py 
enter a word: houses
['hose', 'hoses', 'shoe', 'shoes', 'hues', 'house', 'houses', 'ho', 'us', 'use', 'uses', 'shoe']
$ python matches.py 
enter a word: exams
['same', 'exam', 'mesa']
```

If you want to avoid matches like `shoe` where the ordering of letters is not the same as in the input, just set `RETAIN_ORDERING = True`.

Comment: How does this help with anything? You just hardcoded the answer into the first line... if you time `exams` at the input, it returns `[]`...

Comment: What are you talking about? I did not hardcode the answer; `all_words` is simply a sample dataset. I added more strings to the sample dataset and it still prints the same correct output, so you'd believe me.

Comment: Then why doesn't it print all the correct words if you type in `exams`?

Comment: Which words is it supposed to print for `exams` in your opinion? I'm using a **SAMPLE** dataset; if does not have to work with ANY word. If you add `"same"` to the dataset, it will output it when you enter `exams` (but not when you enter `houses`), but not if it's not in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work...

```
wordlist=[list of words]
solutionlist=[]
userword=[userword[i] for i in range(len(userword))]
for word in wordlist:
    inword=True
    letters=[word[j] for j in range(len(word))]
    for letter in set(letters):
        if letters.count(letter)>userword.count(letter):
            inword=False
            break
    if inword:
        solutionlist.append(word)

for line in solutionlist:
    print line
```

Comment: sorry, I missed a part of the question :) deleted my comment.

Comment: This is a great foundation to work from. The only issue with I encountered is it prints words that aren't in the text file.